# Gatling to check if a button is clickable

Tags: gatling

I have this application where users answer a survey and if there are any questions that are mandatory, the submit survey button will not be active (not clickable- grayed out) if they are not answered. Gatling is now passing the test even if the button is not clickable, is there any 'check' method that we can impose to see that the test fails if the button is not clickable? Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Gatling is not a browser but a HTTP (amongst other protocols) client, so it doesn't know anything about "clickable". You have to check based on response content.